# Gradient part of the image displays white doted a long the bending on email clients

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I'm new to Photoshop and I'm building an HTML email template for the client with the PSD file provided.

This is the image part I cropped and what it displays in the normal browsers:

[image]

And below is what it looks like in the email clients ( IE only ):
[image]

I have tried to save for web & device as various extensions like png, gif, and jpg to remove those white dots but no lucks.

Could anyone tell me how to remove this?

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: As in the image, it is IE8 and IE9, but they are only used to display the email in email client (gmail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with these steps !
 -- duplicate the gradient layer alone
  -- fill it with black and transparency gradient on it,
  -- Just expand it little bit, till it matches with original gradient layer corner.
or
while save as web option select quality as bicubic smooth or near neighbor option